# Spring Cassandra Converter to convereter the null Boolean object to false

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I have entity which has Boolean field. It is possible that its value can be null in Database.

I am using spring Cassandra 2.0.1.RELEASE

So I have tried to write a converter to convert the null values to false.

```
@Table("employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -3723276354723269571L;

  @PrimaryKey
  private final String id;

  @Column
  private final Boolean isPermanant;

 }
```

Converter

```
@Bean
CassandraCustomConversions cassandraCustomConversions() {
    List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
    converters.add(new CounterDataReadConverter());
    return new CassandraCustomConversions(converters);
}

static class CounterDataReadConverter implements Converter<Boolean, Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean convert(Boolean source) {
        System.out.println(source);
        if (source != null) {
            return source;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I query the database using cassandra operations

```
Select select = QueryBuilder.select().from("keyspace", "employee");
List<Employee> employees = cassandraOperations.select(select, Employee.class);      
System.out.println(employees);
```

As the value is null, it is never reaching converter. If the value is false it is invoking converter.

Am I missing anything?